# How to add background image to a UItable cell which is created dynamically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicolor

***I'm creating a custom dynamic table which I used for creating a drop down on button click and it works fine. Now all the cells of table are plain white. I'm able to add background to table but having trouble adding background to the cell. This is a piece of code where I create the table. How will I add background image to my cell in this and also for its highlighted state? And is it also possible to customize its border?***

```
- (void)createMenuTable {

    int totalItems = [self.menuArray count];

    float originalHeight = (MENU_CELL_HEIGHT * totalItems);

    float tableHeight = (originalHeight > self.frame.size.height)? (self.frame.size.height - (originalHeight > self.frame.size.height)): originalHeight;

    float xOrigin = 0;

    if (self.menuBarPosition == POSITION_RIGHT) {
        xOrigin = self.frame.size.width - MENU_TABLE_WIDTH;
    }

    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, MENU_TABLE_WIDTH, 0);
    menuOptionsTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [menuOptionsTableView setDelegate:self];
    [menuOptionsTableView setDataSource:self];
    [menuOptionsTableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [self addSubview:menuOptionsTableView];

    tableFrame.size.height = tableHeight;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
        menuOptionsTableView.frame = tableFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *ParentCellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = (self.menuArray)[indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:MY_FONT_BOLD(14)];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please provide code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Fine, The easiest solution is given in my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code on your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


NSArray *cellSubs = cell.contentView.subviews;
for (int i = 0 ; i < [cellSubs count] ; i++)
{
    [[cellSubs objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
}
    cell.textLable.text = "ABC";
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.backgroundView.frame];
        [bgView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
        bgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg.png"];
        [cell setBackgroundView:bgView];

     return cell;
}
```

Selected cell background

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
 UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selectedcell_bg.png"]]];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

**EDIT**

For macking round ract corner

First add --> `QuartzCore.framework` to your project &
In your ViewController.m file -> Import header file

```
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>
```

..

```
CALayer *cellImageLayer = bgView.layer;
    [cellImageLayer setCornerRadius:9];
    [cellImageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: Let me check with that.

Comment: That seems to take care of first part, is it possible to customize its border, like a rounded corner around cell. And is it possible to give a highlight color for the cell like similar to that of a button?

Comment: i don't know how to do round rect corne. but yes you differ the selected cell color or image by code which i edit on my answer plz see my answer. If you want the round rect corner than you select the image with round rect corner.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is the best answer so far, if I dont get any other best answer with border customization, i'll mark this as the best answer, for now i'll upvote it :)

Comment: for riund rect image corner i added some code in my answer see my code in edit section

Answer (score 1):

Add a line in your following method as shown bellow.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *ParentCellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        UIImageView * img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE.PNG"]];
        [img setHighlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_HIGHLIGHTED_IMAGE.PNG"]];
        [img setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
        [img release];//FOR NON ARC

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = (self.menuArray)[indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:MY_FONT_BOLD(14)];
    return cell;
}
```

This will help you easily.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, wat about other part like adding the image for highlight when selecting and border?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
UIView * bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:correctFrame];
[bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[cell addSubview:bgView];
```

Hope that works for you.

Mike.